# How to make this sub query work

Tags: apex, soql, content

I get this error when I run this query. 
The inner and outer selects should not be on the same object.

```
select Id from contentFolderItem where ParentContentFolderId in
(select Id from contentfolderitem where parentContentFolderId = 
'abcdefggggg')
```

If I split the queries I have to use a for loop which sometimes results in "101 Too many soql queries" error.

I understand why I get both the errors, but I don't know how to fix the problem.

I need to run this soql from apex.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve  by adding an inner query on the same object. Can you not add parentContentFolderId = 'abcdefggggg' in the main query.

Comment: The content structure seems a bit odd since an item can be a folder but the parent is a contentfolder.  Seems like some weird polymorphic stuff going on there but I don't have an org with content populated to test right now.  I think this query might help you out:

select Id from contentFolderItem where parentcontentfolderid in (select id from contentfolder where parentcontentfolderid = 'abcd...')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is called a semi-join (or an anti-join if you use NOT IN).  These are useful for gathering table A if it contains or does not contain some relational object (e.g. find all accounts with a contact named Bob).

```
SELECT Id,Name FROM Account WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact WHERE FirstName = 'Bob')
```

A sub-query is slightly different.  It's a left inner join that grabs all of table A, and any of the table B records (respecting the criteria you give).

```
SELECT Id,Name,(SELECT Id,Name FROM Contacts WHERE FirstName = 'Bob') FROM Account
```

This will give me all accounts whether they have a contact named Bob or not. You can read up more on semi and anti-joins in the documentation here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm

Specific to your issue though, the object you're working with appears to be somewhat abstract.  It appears as though a ContentFolderItem can be either a ContentDocument or a ContentFolder.  You'll notice the ContentFolderItem has a flag called IsFolder.  You can read more on the object here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentfolderitem.htm

In this case you can just query the ContentFolderItem object as a semi-join to the ContentFolder object:

```
SELECT Id FROM ContentFolderItem WHERE ParentContentFolderId IN (SELECT Id FROM ContentFolder where ParentContentFolderId = 'abcd...')
```

This will give you all ContentFolderItems (documents and folders) inside the folder whose parent folder has the Id 'abcd...'.  Normally you could just traverse the relationships upward like this:

```
SELECT Id FROM ContentFolderItem WHERE ParentContentFolder.ParentContentFolderId = 'abcd...'
```

however... this is a special object that requires filtering on Id. You can't run very broad queries on these tables.